I am having problem installing VS Code on Ubuntu 24.04
sudo dpkg -i code_1.89.1-1715060508_amd64.deb  
(Reading database ... 121580 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.89.1-1715060508_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code:amd64 (1.89.1-1715060508) over (1.89.1-1715060508) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:amd64:
 code:amd64 depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.17).
 code:amd64 depends on libatk-bridge2.0-0 (>= 2.5.3).
 code:amd64 depends on libatk1.0-0 (>= 2.2.0).
 code:amd64 depends on libatspi2.0-0 (>= 2.9.90).
 code:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14).
 code:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.16).
 code:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17).
 code:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.5).
 code:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.28).
 code:amd64 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.6.0).
 code:amd64 depends on libcurl3-gnutls | libcurl3-nss | libcurl4 | libcurl3.
 code:amd64 depends on libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14).
 code:amd64 depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.75).
 code:amd64 depends on libexpat1 (>= 2.1~beta3).
 code:amd64 depends on libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2).
 code:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3).
 code:amd64 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17).
 code:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10).
 code:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10) | libgtk-4-1.
 code:amd64 depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2).
 code:amd64 depends on libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~).
 code:amd64 depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.30).
 code:amd64 depends on libnss3 (>= 3.26).
 code:amd64 depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0).
 code:amd64 depends on libx11-6.
 code:amd64 depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1).
 code:amd64 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2).
 code:amd64 depends on libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.4.4-1).
 code:amd64 depends on libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1).
 code:amd64 depends on libxext6.
 code:amd64 depends on libxfixes3.
 code:amd64 depends on libxkbcommon0 (>= 0.5.0).
 code:amd64 depends on libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0).
 code:amd64 depends on libxrandr2.
 code:amd64 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.4).

dpkg: error processing package code:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.4-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code:amd64


apt -f install will fix it. If it can find a solution, then it will install the missing packages, otherwise it will remove code.

If you want to install a deb package using command line, use the apt instead of dpkg to manage all the dependencies automatically.
sudo apt install ./path/to/package.deb

Since you already installed it using dpkg (which cannot automatically install dependencies, use the command sudo apt -f install to install the missing dependencies.
